# Trouble with Async/Await with mySQL result in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have the following code, which is an API call through Express. I need to return an array of quotes, and an array of the parts associated with those quotes. To do so, I'm using async/await, which is working properly in my quotes variable, but I'm getting an empty array in my parts variable.

I believe this has to do with the parts results being pending promises, because when I console log my results within the loop, I get the appropriate values.

I suspect I must be misunderstanding how either async/await works, or how promises/Promise.all works.

Any help understanding why I'm not getting fulfilled promise results is appreciated!

```
router.get('/:pagenum/:dealerno/:modelyear/', async (req, res) => {
  let quotes = await getQuotes(
    req.params.pagenum,
    req.params.dealerno,
    req.params.modelyear
  );

  console.log('MY QUOTES:');
  console.log(quotes); //This returns an array of my quotes, as expected

  let parts = await getQuoteParts(quotes);

  console.log('MY PARTS:');
  console.log(parts); //This returns an array of undefined values
});

function getQuotes(pagenum, dealerno, modelyear) {
  // return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  var q_quote =
    "SELECT quote.id, DATE_FORMAT(quote.timestamp, '%b %d, %Y') AS timestamp, quote.quotenum, quote.quotetype, quote.configtype, quote.sid, quote.tractortype, customer.cus_id, customer.customername, parts.partno, units.type AS fmtype, combos.type AS mmtype FROM GH_savedquoteinfo AS quote JOIN GH_internal_customers AS customer ON quote.cusid=customer.cus_id JOIN GH_savedquoteparts AS parts ON (quote.quotenum = parts.quotenum AND parts.type='unit') LEFT JOIN " +
    modelyear +
    "_fm_units AS units ON (parts.partno = units.model_no AND quote.tractortype='FM') LEFT JOIN " +
    modelyear +
    "_mm_combos AS combos ON (parts.partno = combos.model_no AND quote.tractortype='MM') WHERE quote.dealerno=? AND quote.modelyear=? AND quote.quotetype!='multi' ORDER BY quote.quotenum LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0;";

  let resultHolder = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(q_quote, [dealerno, modelyear], function (
      err_quote,
      result_quote
    ) {
      if (err_quote) {
        console.log('error');
      } else {
        try {
          resultHolder.push(result_quote);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error');
        } finally {
          resolve(resultHolder);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

async function getQuoteParts(quoteResult) {
  let quoteParts = [];
  let quotePartsResult = await Promise.all(
    quoteResult[0].map(async (quote, index) => {
      var q_parts =
        "SELECT * FROM GH_savedquoteparts WHERE quotenum=? AND (type='' OR type='pvcomplete') ORDER BY id";

      connection.query(q_parts, [quote.quotenum], function (
        err_parts,
        result_parts
      ) {
        if (err_parts) {
          console.log('error in parts' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log(result_parts); //This returns an array of my parts
          quoteParts.push(result_parts);
        }
      });
    })
  );

  return quoteParts; 
}
```

Comment: In `getQuoteParts`, you're missing the `new Promise` around `connection.query`.

Comment: This is basically what my problem was. If you put it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an array of undefined values is because you're returning `quotePartsResult` instead of `quoteParts` in which you're pushing values. Since you're running a .map on `quoteResult` and not returning anything inside the map function, it resolves to undefined.

I would like to refactor your code for a better understanding. You should have an array of promises in your Promise.all() call.

Something like:

```
const promises = qouteResult.map(async (quote) => {
  // Your query calls. You can also promisify the callbacks in here using 
  util.promisify()
});

OR

const promises = qouteResult.map(qoute => {

return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  // Your query calls.
  if(success) {
    resolve()
  } else {
    reject()
  }
});
});

const result = await Promise.all(promises);
return result;
```

Comment: You're right – I had tried it both ways, returning from within the loop and also pushing to an array, and I guess I forgot to change it back here. But, sadly, I still get an empty array when I change it to quoteParts.

Comment: @AmyMurphy I have updated my answer. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments mentioned, the main thing I was missing was a new Promise wrapper around my second connection. I also needed a Promise.all within that second function, getQuoteParts. Here's what the final code looked like:

```
router.get('/:pagenum/:dealerno/:modelyear/', async (req, res) => {
  //QUOTES ARRAY
  const quotes = await getQuotes(
    req.params.pagenum,
    req.params.dealerno,
    req.params.modelyear
  );

  const parts = await getQuoteParts(quotes);

  const details = await getPartDescrips(parts, quotes);

  Promise.all([quotes, parts, details]).then((results) => {
    res.send(results);
  });
});

function getQuotes(pagenum, dealerno, modelyear) {
  // return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  const qQuote =
    "SELECT quote.id, DATE_FORMAT(quote.timestamp, '%b %d, %Y') AS timestamp, quote.quotenum, quote.quotetype, quote.configtype, quote.sid, quote.tractortype, customer.cus_id, customer.customername, parts.partno, units.type AS fmtype, combos.type AS mmtype FROM GH_savedquoteinfo AS quote JOIN GH_internal_customers AS customer ON quote.cusid=customer.cus_id JOIN GH_savedquoteparts AS parts ON (quote.quotenum = parts.quotenum AND parts.type='unit') LEFT JOIN " +
    modelyear +
    "_fm_units AS units ON (parts.partno = units.model_no AND quote.tractortype='FM') LEFT JOIN " +
    modelyear +
    "_mm_combos AS combos ON (parts.partno = combos.model_no AND quote.tractortype='MM') WHERE quote.dealerno=? AND quote.modelyear=? AND quote.quotetype!='multi' ORDER BY quote.quotenum DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 0;";

  let resultHolder = [];

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(qQuote, [dealerno, modelyear], function (
      errQuote,
      resultQuote
    ) {
      if (errQuote) {
        console.log(errQuote.message);
      } else {
        try {
          resolve(resultQuote);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function getQuoteParts(quoteResult) {
  var partResults = quoteResult.map((quote, index) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const qParts =
        "SELECT * FROM GH_savedquoteparts WHERE quotenum=? AND (type='' OR type='pvcomplete') ORDER BY type='pvcomplete', type='', id";
      // new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(qParts, [quote.quotenum], function (
        errParts,
        resultParts
      ) {
        if (errParts) {
          console.log('error in PARTS');
        } else {
          resolve(resultParts);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(partResults);
  
}
```

I wrote an article outlining how it works here:
https://medium.com/@amymurphy_40966/node-mysql-chained-promises-vs-async-await-9d0c8e8f5ee1